# How to clear service worker cache programmatically?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a site with a service worker with multiple caches, which have files used for different reasons.  I'd to be able to clear (or delete) one particular cache from my program on demand, not from within the service worker itself.  This is what I've tried:

```
async function clearCache(cacheName) {
  if ('caches' in window) {
    return await caches.delete(cacheName);
  } 
}
```

I can get the cache from the window object, but can't seem to delete it.  I've also tried looping through the cache and deleting all the files individually, but that didn't work either.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that code should delete the cache. (You could simplify it a little bit by omitting the `async/await`, since the code was already returning a promise, but that doesn't really matter.)

If you're not seeing the cache disappear right away, then it's possible that there's a different variable in scope which is maintaining a reference to an open instance of the cache. As per [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache-storage-delete):

> Note: After this step, the existing DOM objects (i.e. the currently referenced Cache, Request, and Response objects) should remain functional.

In practice, that means that if you have an open instance of `cacheName` in scope somewhere, the deletion won't take place until after it's closed or falls out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for cleaning everything from cache programmatically.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
    cacheNames.forEach(function(cacheName) {
      caches.delete(cacheName);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: In which file add these lines of code?